# Remove header/footer from titlepage BEAMER

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I use Beamer for my presentation.
I am using the Berlin theme.
I would like that only the title page (first slide) did not show the header and the footer line indicating the index of the topics, the title, etc.
I tried to use [plain] just after \begin {frame} of the first slide but it takes away the university logo (I don't want to take it off).
How can I solve?
Thank you
[image]

I would like to add the University logo in the same position of all other frames (Berlin theme).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\pngfigspath}{./figures_png_beamer/}

\title{Indagine numerica sulle prestazioni di una turbina eolica ad asse verticale di tipo troposchiano}
\author[UniBG]{\texorpdfstring{\large Alessandro xxx\\ \small Relatore: Chiar.mo xxx\\ \small Correlatore: xxx}{Alessandro xxx}}
\date{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale, xxx}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{\pngfigspath Uni}}
\institute[Uni]{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria meccanica\\Università xxx}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can place the logo manually somewhere with `\insertlogo`. But it would be much easier to help if we had some code to play with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to temporarily deactivate the `headline` and `footline` templates for the titlepage and then reinstate the ones from the `Berlin` theme afterwards. The command to set a specific template is `\setbeamertemplate` and you already found out that `headline/footline` are the corresponding ones you need to change.

To clear them, just call `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` and to reinstate them call `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[miniframes theme]`, be aware to use the right brackets!

Here is how to use it in an extended MWE of yours:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Indagine numerica sulle prestazioni di una turbina eolica ad asse verticale di tipo troposchiano}
\author[UniBG]{\texorpdfstring{\large Alessandro xxx\\ \small Relatore: Chiar.mo xxx\\ \small Correlatore: xxx}{Alessandro xxx}}
\date{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale, xxx}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-grid-100x100bp}}
\institute[Uni]{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria meccanica\\Università xxx}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}%[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}[miniframes theme]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[miniframes theme]

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\frame{A frame}
\frame{Another frame}

\end{document}
```

And this is the title page and first slide:

[image]

Comment: For some reason the reinstating doesn't work with JuanLesPins. theme

Comment: @pmaen what is the JuanLesPins theme?

Comment: one of the presets for beamer presentations. [link](https://www.namsu.de/latex/themes/JuanLesPins.html)

Comment: @pmaen if you are interested in a solution for that, please open a new question with a reference to this question.

Comment: I solved the issue in some other way back than (I don't remember how exactly from the top of my mind). Maybe I'll open a question and answer it myself when I have looked it up. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @pmaen Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by [@TobiBS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559532/36296), but to make this theme independent, one could redefine the head- and footline templates within a group, so this affect the other frames:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Indagine numerica sulle prestazioni di una turbina eolica ad asse verticale di tipo troposchiano}
\author[UniBG]{\texorpdfstring{\large Alessandro xxx\\ \small Relatore: Chiar.mo xxx\\ \small Correlatore: xxx}{Alessandro xxx}}
\date{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale, xxx}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-duck}}
\institute[Uni]{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria meccanica\\Università xxx}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}%[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```